# python scrapy need assitance. I want to save to a (.csv) file. How can I do this?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, save

I'm using debian Bullseye (11.2)
I want to save to a (.csv) file.
How can I do this?

```
from scrapy.spiders import CSVFeedSpider


class CsSpiderSpider(CSVFeedSpider):
    name = 'cs_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/']
    start_urls = ['http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science//feed.csv']
    # headers = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'image_link']
    # delimiter = '\t'

    # Do any adaptations you need here
    #def adapt_response(self, response):
    #    return response

    def parse_row(self, response, row):
        i = {}
        #i['url'] = row['url']
        #i['name'] = row['name']
        #i['description'] = row['description']
        return i
```

Comment: You can check out the `Feeds` export from the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-csv). By importing `from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess`, and saving the output as a `.csv` file.

Comment: The link you provided in `start_urls` does not point to a valid csv file. If you have a valid url to a csv file the you can download the file using scrapy and the `FilesPipeline`. Read about it in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using the `FEEDS` export from scrapy.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class CsspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cs_spider' 
    start_urls = ['http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, callback = self.parse_row
            )

    def parse_row(self, response):
        yield {
            'test':response.text
        }

process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEEDS':{
            'data.csv':{
                'format':'csv'
            }
        }
    }
)
process.crawl(CsspiderSpider)
process.start()
```

Will save the output of your file into `.csv` format. Furthermore, To specify columns to export and their order use `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS`. You can read more about this in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-csv)

In the command line you can run:

```
scrapy crawl cs_spider -o output.csv
```

However, when running the above in the command line make sure to comment out all the code from `process` and below.

Comment: Unless you intend to run the spider from a script, the `CrawlerProcess` is not necessary. You can simply provide the same value of the `FEEDS` setting in the `custom_settings` spider argument. Then in that case, there's no need to provide the `-o` flag on the terminal.